# Iterative Plotting on maps using gmplot in python without overwritting

Tags: python

This is a code to plot data by calling googlemaps API.But this code is printing only last values while overwriting the previously plotted segments one after the other.

```
 for i in range(0,data_length-1):  
       latsub=[]
       longsub=[]
       latd1=latmap[i]
       lond1=longmap[i]    
       latd2= latmap[i+1]
       lond2 =longmap[i+1]
       latsub.append(latd1)
       latsub.append(latd2)
       longsub.append(lond1)
       longsub.append(lond2)
       gm_obj[i]=gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(latmap[i],longmap[i],100)
       print("hello")
       gm_obj[i].plot(latsub,longsub,color= colorid[i],edge_width=10)
       gm_obj.draw(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\gpsplotroad1.html")
```

Can someone provide some code or function to prevent overwriting of gmplot?

Comment: define the lists outside the for loop and then append the values to it. For each iteration your lists are getting redefined.

Comment: I want to color each segment between two consecutive lat and long with different colors based on its colorid.and that particular gmplot syntax only supports lists.

Comment: Is there any alternative to gmplot that does not overwrite previously printed lines on the map?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

```
latsub=[]
longsub=[]

for i in range(0,data_length-1):
     #Your code to append list values
```

Each time your loop runs new list is getting created in your code.

Comment: Actually I want to draw segmented maps i.e. between any two consecutive latitudes and longitudes I want to denote a different colorid thats why I have decared latsub and longsub inside the loop so that everytime plot function will have only 2 consecutive lat long points to plot on the map. But its not happening. only last two lat long points are being plotted on the map at the end of the loop with the corresponding colorid.

Comment: So anyone can help me out in this case to do dynamic segmentation of the google maps using python. My final query is I have a list of latitudes and longitudes say 134 nos. Between every corresponding lat and longs I want t denote a different colour....Is it possible in python using any other command